# Can I change fix the month and date into 01-01 for each year in xls data in R?

Tags: r, regex, date, aggregate, zoo

I need to aggregate quarterly data from FRED into annual. 
The one I found without change the class into zoo is the following

```
annual.proprietors_income <- apply.yearly(xts(quarter.proprietors_income),sum)
```

This apply.yearly nicely

```
2014-10-01 5263.208
2015-10-01 5275.225
2016-10-01 5367.733
2017-10-01 5543.883
```

Can I fix it into 2014-01-01, 2015-01-01, 2016-01-01 and so on? It is the first quarterly date for each year... This really consumes a lot of my time......:(

Comment: Please provide a representative sample of the data you are in using in the same format (possibly using `dput`) and make sure you are providing your code, your errors, and what you ideally would like to see as output. Making the problem reproducible will lead to lots of people enthusiastically helping you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions and the function `gsub` you can convert cases like "-10-01 ..." to just "-01-01", for example:

```
gsub("-\\d\\d-\\d\\d[:print:]*","-01-01",annual.proprietors_income)
```

Where \d means any single digit (0-9) and [:print:]* means zero or more printable characters (things like spaces, digits, punctuation marks) to take care of the numeric timestamp after the date.

You can find some helpful examples here: http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php

Comment: Weird thing is this doesn't work for me... SInce it is xts class, I used gsub("-\\d\\d-\\d\\d[:print:]*","-01-01",index(annual.proprietors_income)), and seemed to work in screen. But when I type annual.proprietors_income, it is still -10-01...

Comment: Hi @user9620331 you would need to assign the gsub to annual.proprietors_income, so annual.proprietors_income <- gsub(.... anyhoo glad you were able to work a solution to this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. I leave here for future reference.
I used the following command and it worked like a charm.

```
 index(annual.proprietors_income) <- update(index(annual.proprietors_income), month=1, day=1)
```

I looked at 
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/override-date-in-xts-time-series-td4648222.html

and https://rpubs.com/mohammadshadan/288218